# Picking random variable in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variables, random

I am trying to pick a random dictionary variable from a list. I start out by choosing a random variable from the list `emotelist`.

```
import random
emotelist = [bored]
emotechosen = random.choice(emotelist)
emotename = emotechosen['emote']
emoteframe = emotechosen['frame']
bored = {'emote':'bored', 'frame':135}
print emotename
print emoteframe
```

But I recieve an error of

> NameError: name 'bored' is not defined

Thank you for the help. I should have defined my variables in the list before creating the list of variables.

Comment: In line 2 you access bored but you never defined bored before

Comment: And what did you *expect* to be produced from this code? Your code tries to use a name `bored` before it is bound to on a much later line.

Comment: Always read the error. They're meant for humans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define `bored` **before** creating a  list that holds it:

```
import random
# move bored definition here:
bored = {'emote':'bored', 'frame':135}
# now use it in a list construction
emotelist = [bored]
emotechosen = random.choice(emotelist)
emotename = emotechosen['emote']
emoteframe = emotechosen['frame']
print emotename
print emoteframe
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define **bored** before using it:

```
import random
bored = {'emote':'bored', 'frame':135}
emotelist = [bored]
emotechosen = random.choice(emotelist)
emotename = emotechosen['emote']
emoteframe = emotechosen['frame']
```

Comment: But the OP defines a variable `bored` later on. The rest of the code is a mess too.

Comment: When doing this, it picks the string bored, so emotename and emoteframe can't get the dictionary values because strings aren't dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to print a random dictionary value:

```
from random import choice

bored = {'emote':'bored', 'frame':135}
print bored[choice(bored.keys())]
```